# AWS Elastic Beanstalk correctly configure security group failed to connect to upstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

when I try to deploy my NodeJs application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Nginx I get the following error:

```
2020/04/29 17:15:51 [error] 5054#0: *993 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.9.65, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "172.31.29.89"
```

First of all why in the world is it trying to connect on port 8081? It should be connecting on port 80 and allowing HTTP traffic.
I assume this is a security group issue. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

My EC2 Instances have the following security group configuration (outbound allows all traffic):
[image: EC2 Instance Config]

My load balancer security group configuration is as follows:

Inbound:
[image: Load Balancer Inbound Rules]

Outbound:
[image: Load Balancer Outbound Rules]

I am sure its a silly stupid mistake but I've spent the last few days scouring the internet and meticulously going through my configuration to no avail. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out nothing was wrong with my security group. It was the code that failed to require a module. if you get `connect() failed (111: Connection refused)` errors double check your code and make sure it's not requiring or erroring in any way. After much digging, I found this was not a security group issue.